# Error building Qt 5.3.0 on Windows 7 x64: idc.exe qguiapplication.cpp could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7, 64-bit, qt5, build-error

I downloaded `qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.0.zip` and am trying to build on Windows 7 x64.   I was able to build Qt 5.2.1 earlier on this same machine, so I'm mystified why 5.3.0 is not working.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 x64 Win64 Command Prompt.

I have tried several configurations:

```
configure -prefix %CD%\qtbase -developer-build -opensource -nomake tests -no-opengl -no-angle -plugin-sql-sqlite -platform win32-msvc2008 -make-tool jom

configure -prefix %CD%\qtbase -developer-build -opensource -nomake tests -opengl desktop -plugin-sql-sqlite -platform win32-msvc2008 -make-tool jom

configure -prefix %CD%\qtbase -developer-build -opensource -nomake tests -opengl desktop -platform win32-msvc2008 -make-tool jom
```

I get the same result for each:  3 identical message boxes pop up, then eventually the build ends with errors.

The message boxes are:

---

### Microsoft Visual C++ Debug Library

Debug Error!

Program: c:\Qt\qt530_x64\qtbase\bin\idc.exe
Module: 5.3.0
File: kernel\qguiapplication.cpp
Line: 999

This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows".

Available platform plugins are: minimal, offscreen, windows.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

### (Press Retry to debug the application)

### Abort   Retry   Ignore

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working for what I need, anyway.  I deleted everything in the folders:
qtdeclarative
qtwebkit
qtwebkit-examples

because those modules were causing build failures, and I don't need them.

Then, I configured with:

```
configure -prefix %CD%\qtbase -developer-build -opensource -nomake tests -no-compile-examples -no-opengl -no-angle -plugin-sql-sqlite -platform win32-msvc2008 -qtlibinfix _mycompany -make-tool jom
```

and jom built Qt 5.3.0 successfully.